# Custom drawable with ImageView

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, android-drawable

I have already an 'ImageView' with these parameters:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and set custom `Drawable` :

```
public class HexDrawable extends Drawable {

    private Path hexagonPath;
    private float mWidth, mHeight;
    private int mBackgroundColor;
    private int mStrokeColor;
    private int mStrokeWidth;

    public HexDrawable(){
        init();
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
        mBackgroundColor = color;
    }

    public void setStrokeWidth(int width) {
        mStrokeWidth = width;
    }

    public void setStrokeColor(int color) {
        mStrokeColor = color;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return 60;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return 60;
    }

    private void init() {
        hexagonPath = new Path();
        mBackgroundColor = Color.BLUE;
        mStrokeColor = Color.GREEN;
        mStrokeWidth = 4;
    }

    private void calculatePath() {
        float p = mStrokeWidth / 2;
        float w = mWidth - 2 * p;
        float h = mHeight - 2 * p;
        float r = h / 2;
        float a = (float) (r / Math.sqrt(3));
        PointF X = new PointF(p + a + r / 2, p);
        PointF Y = new PointF(p + a + r , p);
        PointF A = new PointF(p + a, p + 0f);
        PointF B = new PointF(p + 0f, p + r);
        PointF C = new PointF(p + a, p + 2 * r);
        PointF D = new PointF(p + w - a, p + 2 * r);
        PointF E = new PointF(p + w, p + r);
        PointF F = new PointF(p + w - a, p + 0);
        hexagonPath.moveTo(Y.x, Y.y);
        hexagonPath.lineTo(A.x, A.y);
        hexagonPath.lineTo(B.x, B.y);
        hexagonPath.lineTo(C.x, C.y);
        hexagonPath.lineTo(D.x, D.y);
        hexagonPath.lineTo(E.x, E.y);
        hexagonPath.lineTo(F.x, F.y);
        hexagonPath.lineTo(X.x, X.y);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        mWidth = bounds.width();
        mHeight = bounds.height();
        calculatePath();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(mStrokeColor);                    // set the color
        paint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);               // set the size
        paint.setDither(true);                    // set the dither to true
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);       // set to STOKE
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);    // set the join to round you want
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);      // set the paint cap to round too
        paint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(mStrokeWidth));   // set the path effect when they join.
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawPath(hexagonPath, paint);
        canvas.clipPath(hexagonPath, Region.Op.INTERSECT);
        canvas.drawColor(mBackgroundColor);
        canvas.drawPath(hexagonPath, paint);
        canvas.save();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It seems that `ImageView` use all width in this case.

How to implements `Drawable` correctly to use it with `ImageView`?

Comment: Can you post the code of your custom drawable?

Comment: @Brucelet done, added example code

Comment: I looked at your code and drawable sits in `Imageview` perfectly. Imageview may occupy additional width (as it may take rectangular or square shape) but you can only see hexagonal drawable. Sorry but..  What is the actual question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of the problem was clip mode.

Its better to use `canvas.clipPath(hexagonPath, Region.Op.REPLACE);`

Also, question example works well with ImageView, but after deep investigation I undestand, that at android 5.0 and above this drawable is used at drawableLeft in `TextView`. 
Also its not need to override `getIntrinsicHeight`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely correct:

[image]

This is how I fill `ImageView` (in `onCreate()` of activity):

```
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hexImageView)).setImageDrawable(new HexDrawable());
```

Layout of the `Activity` on the screenshot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hexImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

If I replace `wrap_content` with value, hexagon as expected is changing its size.

Tested on Android 6.0 and 4.3.

Just one tip - instead of hardcoded values in `getIntrinsicHeight()` and `getIntrinsicWidth()`, it might be better to use `dimens` instead.